# .NET 6/7 Migration from System.Drawing.Common to Microsoft.Maui.Graphics

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, .net-maui

With .NET 7 System.Common.Drawing is no longer useable in not windows platforms. I like to migrate my application to Microsoft.Maui.Graphics (as Microsoft suggests on their breaking changes page for .NET 6/7).
They support GDI+ on windows, which is great since it minimizes the side effects for migration. On Linux or MacOS I can use the SkiaImage implementation.

However it’s not clear, how to achieve this. The documentation is currently very limited. From source code I found the `IImageLoaderService` and a couple of implementations as well as for IImage.

Depending on the platform I would register the right `IImageLoaderService` and everything should work.

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOsPlatform(OsPlatform.Windows) 
{ 
  services.AddSingleton<IImageLoaderService, GDIImageLoaderService>()
} 
else 
{
services.AddSingleton<IImageLoaderService, SkiaImageLoaderService>()  
}
```

So far in theory. However after referencing the `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics` Nuget only `IImageLoaderService` is available.

How do I achieve to register the `GDIImageLoaderService` (or how the service is called to use gdi+) on windows?

Comment: Since this question got a little bit attention. 
I created my own IImage/IImageService-Implemenation with support for (GDI+)/System.Drawing-Images and SkiaImages. If there is enough need, I would create a nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

I thought `System.Drawing.Common` was only being removed for non-windows platforms. Also, isn't `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics` still experimental?  Well, [GitHub still says so](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics) (which is interesting). Anyway, why not use `SkiaImageLoaderService` for Windows as well if you really want to change this?

Also, there is an open bug about this: https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/issues/422

Also the whole of Maui.Graphics repo does not have [GDIImageLoaderService](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/search?q=GDIImageLoaderService).

Actually, nothing on GitHub has [this class](https://github.com/search?q=GDIImageLoaderService) so I am guessing it might not be out yet. Also the Microsoft docs say to use [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action)

You can try this, I guess:

```
#if WINDOWS
    services.AddSingleton<IImageLoadingService, Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Win2D.SkiaImageLoadingService>();
#endif
```

Comment: Yes for non windows-platforms system.drawing is dropped(1st sentence of my question). Why does Microsoft suggest migrating to an experimental library? In GitHub there are all needed implementations for gdi interaction in https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/tree/main/src/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.GDI.Winforms. just the service is missing it seems.

Comment: I might have missed it my bad

Comment: Yeah Service is the Main Class though right?

Comment: Yes I could migrate to SkiaSharp, but I like the idea to have an abstraction layer inbetween especially after this system.drawing chaos. For .NET6 I enabled the runtime flag. In .NET 7 it’s removed.

Comment: In that case, guess you will have to wait...

Comment: Yes but that’s not an option. It seems Libgdiplus in Linux has a memory leak. My app relies heavily on bitmap operations.